# Equation of a great circle passing through two points

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I've searched everywhere for something to help me with this problem, but I can't find anything. What I want to calculate is the midpoint between two locations (latitude and longitude) on a sphere. The midpoint must lie on the shortest path between them. And for this, I need the equation of the great circle on this sphere that passes through these two points.

What I tried to do is first start with an arbitrary great circle given by the following parametric equation:

${x=0}$

${y=cos\space \theta}$

${z=sin\space \theta}$

Or:

$\left( \begin{array}{}
0  \\
cos\space \theta  \\
sin\space \theta \end{array} \right)$

Then if we multiply this vector by three rotation matrices $R_x, R_y,$ and $ R_z$ about angles $\alpha, \beta, $ and $\gamma$, and then solve the equations for the rotation angles using our known values of the radius and the coordinates of the two points, we should get the exact equations of this circle in 3D space, but the trigonometric equations are extremely messy and I'm not sure if my assumption is correct.

There must be a statement of the equation somewhere but I just can't find it. What is it?

Perhaps a simpler method would be to calculate the midpoint in geographic coordinates and *then* convert them to cartesian, but I'm not sure how geometry works in geographic coordinates.

Comment: I have worked out the explicit expressions in $(r,\theta)$ of points, geodesics, laplacian, and almost everything else on sphere, where $(r,\theta)$ are local coordinates on the stereographical projection of the sphere minus $N$ onto $R^2.$
If you're desperate enough to want it, tell me!

Comment: @Behnam Yes it can be found using stereographical projection. But as long as Hex4869 needs this very specific resul, it's shorter, as he considers, to transform spherical -> cartesian -> doing the businness in cartesian -> back to spherical.

Comment: But, wait  minute! If we use spherical $(\theta, \phi)$, won't the answer be the average of the two $\theta$'s and the two $\phi$'s? Just a guess.

Comment: No risk. Of course, if  $(\theta_k,\lambda_k) \ k=1,2$ are not far away one from the other, we know that the result will not be very different from the average you are speaking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the following, we consider that we are working on a unit sphere ($\|V_1\|=\|V_2\|=1$).

If your longitude and latitude coordinates are $(\theta_k,\lambda_k) \ k=1,2.$ Let

$$V_1=\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta_1 \cos \lambda_1 \\ \sin \theta_1 \cos \lambda_1 \\ \sin \lambda_1 \end{bmatrix} \ \ \ V_2= \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta_2 \cos \lambda_2 \\ \sin \theta_2 \cos \lambda_2 \\ \sin \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Set $V_3=V_1+V_2$, and $V_4=\dfrac{V_3}{\|V_3\|}$: it is the desired point.

If one desires the **spherical** coordinates
of $V_4$ out of its cartesian coordinates $(a,b,c)$, it suffices to set :
$$\lambda = \text{asin}(c) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \theta = \text{asin}(\dfrac{b}{\cos \lambda})$$

**Remark :** if one wants a parametrized equation for the great circle passing through $V_1$ and $V_2$, here is a classical way to obtain it (cometimes called "orthonormalization"). It suffices to obtain an orthogonal basis of plane $(P)$ defined by $V_1$ and $V_2$. This is easily done by taking as first vector $V_1$ and as a second vector a linear combination $V=\alpha V_1+\beta V_2$ such that $\|V\|^2=1$ and $V \perp V_1 \iff V \cdot V_1=0$, generating two equations with two unknowns (let us recall that we have assumed that $\|V_1\|=\|V_2\|=1$):

$$\begin{cases}\alpha^2 +\beta^2+ 2 d \alpha \beta &=&1\\\alpha+d \beta=0\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

(where $d$ is defined as the dot product $d:=V_1\cdot V_2$) which is amenable to a quadratic equation with two solutions (in general) because its discriminant is $>0$.

Let $W_1=\alpha V_1+\beta V_2$ be one of these two solutions ; the looked for parametric equation of the great circle passing through  $V_1$ and $V_2$ is

$$V = \cos(t) V_1 + \sin(t) W_1$$

Comment: Wow, as simple as that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Elegant solution. Given the reasoning is not explained, one way to think of this is that V_3 is the vector addition of V_1 and V_2 so will point in the direction of the mid point.  V_4 normalises V_3 so it lies on the unit sphere, and so is the projection of the mid point onto the unit sphere.  Also note that the normal order for longitude and latitude is latitude-longitude.

Comment: An ugly formula completely in spherical coordinates: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180422/simplify-closed-formula-for-distance-preserving-great-circle-spherical-coordinat

Comment: How can I use this to draw a path a long a great circle between two points on a map? I want to use the equirectangular projection for example.

Comment: @Kuba Szymanowski If I understand well you question, you want to parameterize the path between $V_1$ and $V_2$ ? Directly, set $V_t :=(1-t)V_1+tV_2$, then $W_t:=V_t/\|V_t\|$ ($t \in [0,1]$).

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you! I finally got it to work. I was stuck because I thought I had to multiply "a"(first value of the vector) by the sin(c) whereas I just have get the arcsine of "c". Please consider renaming the vector coordinates to x,y,z to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is $_t:=(1−)_11+_2$ really the parameterized curve on the great circle.  I don't really believe it.  That formula is assuming euclidian geometry.  Right?

Comment: @Jim Newton No : $_t:=(1−)_1+_2$ would define a straight line. I just added how to obtain the parametric equation of this great circle under the title : **Remark**